# Application of Borel Cantelli Lemma and Markov inequality

Tags: probability

I have a homework problem that requires assistance.

Given that $(X_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ are i.i.d random variables taking values from $\mathbb{N}$, and $P(X_1=i)=p_i>0\  \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$. 
Let $D_n$ be the cardinality of the set $\left\{X_1,...,X_n\right\}$. 
Show that $D_n\to\infty$ almost surely 
and ${D_n \over n}\to 0$ in probability.

I know that to prove almost sure statements, one has to use Borel Cantelli lemma. However, I encounter difficulty in defining the events to apply the lemma.

Next, for the second question, I intend to use Markov inequality in this way:
$P(|{D_n \over n}-0|\geq \epsilon)=P({D_n \over n}\geq \epsilon)\leq {{E({D_n \over n}})\over \epsilon}\to 0 \ as\ n \to \infty$. The expectation $E({D_n \over n})$ seems hard to compute.

Any comments and assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions: For the first question, you really need to show that $\liminf_n D_n=\infty$ almost surely. Equivalently, show that for any finite $c$, you have that $\liminf_nD_n>c$ almost surely. The intuition is the following: fix a set $\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$. Suppose you now add extra $X_i$ to this set. The chance that the cardinality stays the same is a geometric random variable, so the probability is falling off exponentially. Equivalently, the chance of staying below a fixed $c$ should be falling off in a similar fashion. Make this rigorous and apply Borel Cantelli to get the conclusion. In other words, the probability that $D_n<c$ occurs for infinitely many $n$ has probability 0.

For the second question, start with $P(|D_n/n-0|\geq \epsilon)$ for the right quantity to bound. As far as computing expectation of $D_n$ goes, try an approach similar to what's described in the last paragraph: calculate $\mathbb{E}[D_{n+1}|D_n]$, the conditional expectation. Also, notice that one crude way of going about it is to show that $\mathbb{E}[D_n]=o(n)$.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the prompt reply. I have edited my question as there is a typo. Apologies. For the first question, what you mean is fix a c, then computed $P(D_n>c)$ should be $1-\Pi{p_i}$ for which the numbers associated to the {p_i}'s have appeared? In addition, for the second problem, can you please further elaborate on computing the conditional expectation? Apologies for asking you for more details as I am new to this course. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it is not $1-\Pi{p_i}$. Is it $1-\sum{p_i}$?